# SSL Connection error on domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I recently bought the SSL certification off GoDaddy in India for my domain [anrweb.com](http://anrweb.com)

The only problem is that the https:// version throws up an "SSL connection error" on Chrome & Firefox. I had incorporated a web.config file that redirects all http requests to https, but that caused the website to not load at all!!

I'm weak in these server-side setups and was looking for help online but was unable to find any resources. Godaddy has no clue whats happening either.

Can someone tell me if I need to make any other changes to my DNS records or any other back-end updates to reflect the SSL installation.

BTW, my domain services, hosting & SSL are all from GoDaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..  Turns out I had to point my DNS to the newly issued static, permanent IP address. Works just fine now. 
GoDaddy should've mentioned this during the setup, but figured it out anyway. 
Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

What version of Firefox and Chrome are you using? I'm able to access the site on Chrome 40.0.2214.91. The SSL Labs test https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=anrweb.com does not indicate any handshake errors although your choice and ordering of cipher suites could use some cleanup. https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_Apache2.html has the recommended SSLCipherSuite value.